# Nginx. Show full configuration expanding the includes

Tags: nginx

So I know that to see what Nginx is using as configuration, one can use `Nginx -T`, but it doesn't expands the includes.

Since I would like to refactor the Nginx config but there are too many includes, I would like to see the includes expanded, to see the entire config.

Is there a way?